# How to give title and subtitle to a material design button?

Tags: android

I want to make a material button having a title and subtitle

eg:- title with big text and subtitle with small text.

Comment: It is better you can create a LinearLayout having Two textView(s). 1. for Title and 2. for subtitle. And you can also set Click Listener to LinearLayout which can work as Button.

Answer (score 0):

**The Simple way is-**

You can Use a Layout as a button. In the layout you can Use a Title and Subtitle and You set the SetOnClickListner on the Layout.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="methodClick"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtitle"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```